# Using jQuery fileupload to Spring controller, parameters are not correctly encoded

Tags: jquery, spring, file-upload, utf-8, character-encoding

I am using jquery file upload to upload files from the client side. Then my datas are handled on the server side (which is a Spring application). I use the asynchronous method [send](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data).

Files and data are correctly sent, but I got a problem with accents. As you can see on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by1rybzn/7/) (you have to add a file before sending), datas seems to be well encoded on the client side.

I send my data manually by doing :

```
$form.fileupload(
   'send', 
   {
      files: filesList,
      formData: {nickname: 'ééééééé'}
   }
)
```

As it can be seen below, datas seems ok in the POST header.
[image]

But when I read the value parameter back in the Spring MVC application, I can see that value is not properly encoded.

[image]

I try to encode the value with `encodeURIComponent` but here is what I get from the server side : `%C3%A9%C3%A9%C3%A9%C3%A9%C3%A9%C3%A9%C3%A9`.

Why parameters are not correctly encoded? Maybe the problem is from the server?

EDIT : after more researches, I've found that content-type is defined as the following in the header : `Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryIhNpyB8xBBcA4blE`. But it doesn't specify `utf-8`, I think the problem comes is here.

EDIT 2 : I set the contentType of the ajax query to `'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'` but I got an error from the server side : `Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`

EDIT 3 : in the library jquery-file-upload, content-type (in ajax request) is set to `false`. Because it is the required content-type, to send files. In my case, I'm sending both datas and files, that's why I get a problem.

Comment: Is webpage charset UTF-8?

Comment: Yes it is but apprently not the ajax call. I'm researching how to change the content-type to utf-8.

Comment: Can you place whole code? Try to set in your ajax PHP this code in first line `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` also look your PHP or HTML file is ANSI or Unicode file?

Comment: The problem is not from the server side. It's the ajax call. It does not specify the charset to utf-8. Here is the content-type : Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarysHYjfn1xgjgWJ0ij

Comment: If this setup not work `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"` then problem is in your file. Open Notepad++ create new file and save file like Unicode. Copy/Paste your code and try.

Comment: No no no, the changes in the files are done. (I can see the source code of the file from Google Chrome).

Comment: To exclude the obvious, given you're somehow implying that it works fine when you don't interpret the request as a file upload request, are you indeed setting `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` before extracting the request payload in servlet? If not, then that's the cause of your problem (but it would have failed the same way when you didn't upload a file at all ...)

Comment: Strangely, it's not set. And more strangely again, accents are correctly interpreted with any other ajax calls (that set the content-type to utf-8). Now, it's seems complicated to set the content-type when posting both form data and files. Content-type is needed to be set to false to post files, so how to force the content-type to utf-8?

Comment: Stop fiddling around in client side. It's doing all fine. FormData is implicitly always UTF-8. The server side is just incorrectly interpreting it as ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. Again, have you tried `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` before calling any of `request.getXxx()` methods? If you did, but it didn't work, then please tell how you're extracting the form data parts? Using Servlet 3+ native API or a 3rd party API like Apache Commons FileUpload?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I'm using Spring, and may be the multipartResolver is not set to "utf-8".

Comment: Gosh. Spring is not part of Java EE framework. It's Java EE's competitor. In the future tell that you're using Spring not Java EE, that would have clarified a lot :) I've already edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Yeah yeah I know. I wanted to be as generic as possible that's why I talk about Java EE. That was a mistake. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the server side. As I use Spring and a multipart resolver, it was needed to specify the encoding. So I changed this :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
</bean>
```

To this :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8"/>
</bean>
```

And it's working perfectly!